# Remove Sale Price from Google Content API for Shopping using PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-shopping-api, google-content-api

I'm able to **update (*change with another price*)** the product sale price in my Google Merchant Feed via Google Content API for Shopping usign PHP language.

Example. A product with 40% discount (Original Price = 100.00 EUR, Sale Price = 60.00 EUR):

```
$product = new Google_Service_ShoppingContent_Product();
$product->setOfferId($myProductId);
$product->setContentLanguage($idData[1]);
$product->setTargetCountry($idData[2]);
$product->setChannel($idData[0]);

$price = new Google_Service_ShoppingContent_Price();
$price->setValue(100.00);
$price->setCurrency('EUR');

$product->setPrice($price);

$salePrice = new Google_Service_ShoppingContent_Price();
$salePrice->setValue(60.00);
$salePrice->setCurrency('EUR');

$product->setSalePrice($salePrice);
```

I'm not able to remove this discount, I want my product Final Price 100.00 EUR again. I tried with:

```
$product->setSalePrice(NULL);
```

but I got a fatal error:

> Argument 1 passed to
> Google_Service_ShoppingContent_Product::setSalePrice() must be an
> instance of Google_Service_ShoppingContent_Price

I also tried setting the value to 0

```
$salePrice = new Google_Service_ShoppingContent_Price();
$salePrice->setValue(0.00);
$salePrice->setCurrency('EUR');
```

but Google disapprove my offer.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the sale price effective date in the past, like this:

```
$saleStartDate = date(DateTime::ISO8601, strtotime('-5 days'));
$saleEndDate = date(DateTime::ISO8601, strtotime('-1 day'));
$product->setSalePriceEffectiveDate($saleStartDate . '/' . $saleEndDate);
```

Haven't tried it, but hopefully should work.